# Java 7 won't work in mac osx 10.8.2

Tags: java, macos, terminal, minecraft

I tried to play minecraft but it wont even open. some couple days ego i was uploading my app to the app store and i was having trouble so i found this comands on a website to solve the problem.

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0
```

but i after i did that minecraft and the java settings won't work. I also tried to download java and install it again but it still doesn't work. Anyone noes how to fix this?
-thanks

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?" What happens when you type java or javac?

Comment: 1.5 stands for Java 5; try 1.6 if 1.7 did not work. I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are running all system updates on Mountain Lion, you should have Java 6 installed. Try running this command on the commandline:

`java -version`

The output should be

```
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

if you are up to date. I take it that this is not what you are getting. So try

`ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions`

This should give you

```
total 64
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 20 17:46 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 20 17:46 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 20 17:46 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 20 17:46 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 20 17:46 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 20 17:46 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  272 Oct 20 17:47 A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    1 Oct 20 17:46 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   59 Oct 20 17:46 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
```

Again, this would indicate that Java 6 is installed and used when you run applications. If that is the case, then your problem with Minecraft lies somewhere else.

If any of these outputs is not what is listed above, try running a system update, and if that doesn't fix it, post the output to the above commands with your original post so we might be able to help you.

Comment: The question is off-topic. He wants help on running a game server. There's no 'programming' going on ehre.

Comment: i run  `java -version` but this message shows up: java: command not found